# Do legacy surnames have to be unique?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Obviously character names are unique per server, but are legacy surnames as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, legacy names are unique per server and all your alt toons will have the same legacy name on that server.

If I picked "StackExchange" as a legacy name on one server, no one else can pick that name on that server. But if they moved to another server where it wasn't taken, then it's up for grabs.

Better to identify people's alts with.

Don't believe me? Take a look [here](http://swtorhub.com/exclusive-legacy-system-interview) and [here](http://www.oldrepublic.net/229-swtor-legacy-system-explained.html).

Comment: I think the -1 because he means if the legacy names are unique... meaning for example if i take the Stackexchange legacy name, he can't take it because i already have it.

Comment: I tried to clarify that legacy names are unique PER server (all your alt toons will have the same legacy name on that server). So if I picked "StackExchange" as a legacy name on one server, no one else can pick that name on THAT server. But if they moved to another server where it wasn't taken, then it's up for grabs.

Comment: Oooh right, i misread the awnser then... but i'm not the one giving a -1... ill give you a +1 to even it out tho ;)

Comment: Much obliged. :)

Answer (score 3):

No.  This restriction was removed during the latest server merges, with [Patch 1.3.7](http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/1.3.7/952012).  In the first server merge I was required to change my Legacy name due to the constraint, but after the second merge I was able to change it back.